# Modal is showing all records for variable when it should show one?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm calling var MessageBodyFull in the Modal and want to see just the message body for the specific record, but all the records show. I've tried moving the modal to different places in the stack, working around the php for loop, and nothing seems to work.

Added context: The 'LIMIT 10' is limiting the Datatable to 10 records showing the first 65 characters of the message body. Each record has a link to the modal where I'd like show the full message body, but currently when the link is clicked the modal includes the full message body for all 10 records.

**View** (Relevant Snippet)

```
<table id="tableDataset">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th><i class="icon-briefcase"></i> Recipient</th>
         <th class="hidden-xs"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i> Message Body</th>
         <th><i class="icon-bookmark"></i> Date</th>
         <th><i class="icon-bell"></i> Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <?foreach($letter_feed as $feed_item): ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?=$feed_item->Recipient?></td>
            <td class="hidden-xs"><?=$feed_item->MessageBody?> <a href="#messageBodyFull" data-toggle="modal">Full Message</a></td>
            <td><?=$feed_item->Created?> </td>
            <td><?=$feed_item->StatusDescription?></td>
         </tr>
      <?endforeach?>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="messageBodyFull" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messageBodyFull">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">STATUS: <?=$feed_item->StatusDescription?></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <?foreach($letter_feed as $feed_item): ?>
            <?=$feed_item->MessageBodyFull?><br><br> <!-- added the breaks to help my eyes with the error -->
        <?endforeach?>
      </div>      
      <div class="modal-footer">    
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Model** (Relevant Snippet)

```
public function get_letter_feed($user_id) { 
$sql = " 
    SELECT 
    l.uuid AS Uuid, 
    ls.`statcode` AS StatusCode, 
    ls.`statname` AS StatusDescription, 
    lst.shortnotes AS Notes, 
    lp.image AS Picture,
    CONCAT(LEFT(l.messages, 65), '') AS MessageBody, 
    l.rcpnt AS Recipient, 
    lst.createdtime AS Created
FROM Letters l
JOIN LetterAT lst ON lst.letterid = l.id AND lst.deleted IS NULL
JOIN LetterST ls ON ls.id=lst.statusId
JOIN LetterIT lp ON lp.letterid = lst.letterid
WHERE 
    l.ownerId = {$this->db->escape($user_id)}
ORDER BY lst.created DESC
LIMIT 10;";
return $this->db->query($sql)->result();  
}
```

**Controller** (Relevant Snippet)

```
public function get_letter_status_feed_html() {
$letter_feed = $this->Letter_model->get_letter_feed($this->user->userId);
$this->load->view('dashboard/snippet/letter_status_feed', array('letter_feed'=>$letter_feed));
}
```

Comment: You might want to add the PHP code as it's likely to help in identifying why (i.e. where the variable for $letter_feed comes from).

Comment: Thanks @Reisclef, added the Model and Controller.

Comment: Instead of manually escaping, is it possible to use prepared statements? They're usually significantly cleaner and dramatically reduce the risk of mistakes.

Comment: Your SQL says `LIMIT 10`. But you say you only want one record?

Comment: Also, your tags need cleaning up. This has nothing to do with Javascript, and if you're using some sort of framework you should include that.

Comment: @miken32 
**re: 'LIMIT 10'**, the 'LIMIT 10' is limiting the Datatable to 10 records showing the first 65 characters of the message body. Each record has a link to the modal where I'd like show the full message body, but currently when the link is clicked the modal includes the full message body for all 10 records. 

**Re: tags**, specifically the modal tags or something else?

Comment: @BrianCurliss I think miken32 means the tags attributed to the post (currently javascript and PHP). Judging by the functions i.e. (db->escape), you might be using a PHP framework, if so, it'd be good to tag it for searchability. Would I be correct in saying that where you say "it shows all records" it is literally all records? Or all records for the user id in the query?

Comment: Correct, we are codeigniter. "It shows all records" means 10 records for the user, not all records in the database.

Comment: I don't understand. You select 10 records, pass those 10 records to a `view()` function and then loop through the 10 records, echoing each one with line breaks between them, and then complain that 10 records are displayed? Just change your limit statement to 1. What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe this will help? [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5f4xr7vj3owjp4u/Screenshot%202015-09-28%2018.14.01.png?dl=0)

The datatable is limited to the 10 most recent items. I'm trying to make the modal only show one the full body message for the contact selected out the the 10 records passed through.

Answer (score 1):

I presume there is an issue with structure of the stack/queue.

**Fix:** Place the variable desired (var MessageBodyFill = MessageBodyFull) in-line with the record selected and call it with document.getElementById().innerHTML into the modal.

**Table**

```
<table id="tableDataset">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th><i class="icon-briefcase"></i> Recipient</th>
     <th class="hidden-xs"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i> Message Body</th>
     <th><i class="icon-bookmark"></i> Date</th>
     <th><i class="icon-bell"></i> Status</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?foreach($letter_feed as $feed_item): ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?=$feed_item->Recipient?></td>
       <!-- FIX --> <td class="hidden-xs"><?=$feed_item->MessageBody?> <a href="#messageBodyFull" class="open-MessageBodyFill btn btn-primary"  data-id="<?=$feed_item->MessageBodyFull?>" data-toggle="modal">Full Message</a></td>  
        <td><?=$feed_item->Created?> </td>
        <td><?=$feed_item->StatusDescription?></td>
     </tr>
  <?endforeach?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**New/Additional Script**

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".open-MessageBodyFill", function () {
    var MessageBodyFull = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body #messageBodyFull").val( MessageBodyFull );
    document.getElementById("messageBodyFull").innerHTML = MessageBodyFull;
    });
</script>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="messageBodyFull" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messageBodyFull">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">STATUS: <?=$feed_item->StatusDescription?></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
     <p type="textarea" name="messageBodyFull" id="messageBodyFull" value=""/> <!-- FIX -->
  </div>      
  <div class="modal-footer">    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```